# Twitter Bootstrap does not work for views other than layout.erb

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra with .erb templates. Bootstrap works when I navigate to the homepage, which is basically the layout.erb. However when I navigate to other pages, I can't see the Bootstrap effect. Any ideas?

Here's my layout.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>"Flitter"</h1>
    <section>
        <%= yield %>
    </section>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Oddly, I can see Bootstrap effects when I access '/home' page. Here's home.erb:

```
<p>Welcome to this site that's all about the 
    songs of the great Frank Sinatra. </p>
<img src="/images/sinatra.jpg" alt="frank sinatra">
```

But I can't see the effect for '/show_user'. Here's show_user.erb:

```
<div>
    <h1> Welcome @<%=@user.name %>. Have fun micro-blogging!</h1>

    <% if @posts != nil %>
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <div>
                <p><%= post.created_at %></p>
                <p><%= post.content %></p>
            </div> 
    <% end %> 
    <% else %>
        <p> no posts created yet </p>
    <%end %>

    <form action="/post" method="POST">
        <div>
            Create new post<br><br>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="post[content]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly you should include jquery.min.js before the bootstrap.min.js. Secondly it's hard to say why it's not working on your other pages, you don't describe how your template setup looks like?

Comment: Okay I edited my post. Hope that helps